# No Hino do Brasil, quem ouviu, quem falou, o que foi que ouviu, o que foi que falou e onde estava quem ouviu e quem falou?

Tags: caso-gramatical

Segundo o PDF com a letra oficial disponibilizado no site do Planalto [(aqui)](https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/conheca-a-presidencia/acervo/simbolos-nacionais/hinos/hinos), a primeira estrofe do Hino Nacional do Brasil é a seguinte:

```
Ouviram do Ipiranga as margens plácidas 
De um povo heróico o brado retumbante, 
E o sol da liberdade, em raios fúlgidos, 
Brilhou no céu da pátria nesse instante.
```

Pergunto:
Quem ouviu, quem falou, o que foi que ouviu, o que foi que falou e onde estava quem ouviu e quem falou ?

Repare que na letra oficial a palavra "as" (antes de "margens" ) **não** tem acento.

Informo ainda que tenho essa dúvida há muitos anos e ela já foi tema de inúmeros debates que tive, por isso já fui ver a letra no site do Planalto em outras ocasiões e em várias outras administrações, então não é erro na letra devido ao atual momento político ou algo assim.
Imagino que o Planalto seja a autoridade máxima em dizer qual a letra oficial do Hino do Brasil. Entretanto, se houver alguma controvérsia a respeito e houver outra versão dessa estrofe ou uma autoridade superior para dizer qual a letra oficial estou querendo saber também.

Adicionalmente, se alguém conseguir além de responder as perguntas escrever essa estrofe em português coloquial seria excelente.

Comment: Toda a gente sabe mas já gora: "quem falou?" - D Pedro I.  "quem ouviu?" - toda agente (alguns dos quais ouviram contar). "O que foi que ouviu?" - o grito do Ipiranga = "É tempo, Independência ou morte". "Onde?" - Margens do Ipiranga, 1822

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Aprovação do Hino Nacional

O órgão responsável pela aprovação do Hino Nacional Brasileiro foi o poder legislativo, que, em 6 de setembro de 1922, assinou o decreto 15.671. O decreto foi assinado por *Epitacio Pessôa*, que na época era senador eleito pela Paraíba.

> Ouviram do Ypiranga as margens placidas
>   De um povo heroico e brado retumbante
>   E o sol da liberdade, em raios fulgidos,
>   Brilhou no céo da Patria nesse instante.

#### Figura de Linguagem

**Hipérbato**

É bastante comum que as pessoas errem quanto à classificação sintática dos termos do Hino Nacional, isto se deve ao fato de ele estar na ordem indireta, conhecida também como *hipérbato*.

> Esta figura de linguagem é caracterizada pela inversão da ordem direta dos termos da oração, que é composta por: [*sujeito* +] *verbo* [+ *complementos verbais* + *adjuntos*].

**Exemplos:**

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Hipérbato                                          │ Ordem Direta                                       │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│É difícil para mim aprender gramática               │ Aprender gramática é difícil para mim              │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Em meu sangue a América se nutre                    │ A América se nutre em meu sangue                   │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Há dois mil anos te mandei meu grito                │ Mandei-te meu grito há dois mil anos               │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Gravai com Buril nos pátrios anais o vosso poder    │ Gravai o vosso poder com Buril nos pátrios anais   │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Quando alguém te destruir, se reconstrua com sua fé │ Reconstrua-se com sua fé quando alguém te destruir │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Personificação / Prosopopeia**

> A figura de linguagem prosopopeia também é conhecida pelos nomes personificação, animização e antropomorfismo. Toda vez que atribuímos atitudes e sentimentos a seres inanimados, pessoas já falecidas, animais, fenômenos da natureza ou figuras imaginárias, estamos criando uma prosopopeia. <sup>[fonte](https://www.figurasdelinguagem.com/prosopopeia/)</sup>

**Exemplos:**

```
┌───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Hoje até o sol está mais feliz.    │ O sol é uma estrela, não fica feliz nem triste. │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│As flores estão dançando ao vento. │ Flores não dançam, o vento é que as agita.      │
└───────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

#### Análise do Hino Nacional

A figura de linguagem supra é bastante utilizada e está em toda parte do Hino Brasileiro. Para exemplificar melhor, faremos uma análise sintática dos termos.

```
    ┌─────────────────────────────────────── Verbo Transitivo Direto
    │                      ┌──────────────── Sujeito Simples
┌───┴───┐ ┌────────────────┴──────────────┐
│Ouviram│ │do Ipiranga as margens plácidas│
└───────┘ └───────────────────────────────┘
          ┌────────────────────────────────── Adjunto Adnominal de Brado
          │                    ┌───────────── Objeto Direto do verbo Ouviram
┌─────────┴────────┐ ┌─────────┴─────────┐
│De um povo heroico│ │o brado retumbante.│
└──────────────────┘ └───────────────────┘
```

Feita a análise sintática, podemos pôr a oração na ordem direta, ficando desta forma:

> As margens plácidas do Ipiranga ouviram o brado retumbante de um povo heroico.

Podes ater achar estranho o fato das margens ouvir. Isso acontece pois nos deparamos com outra figura de linguagem, a personificação.

Esta oração quer dizer que quando Dom Pedro disse a célebre frase, o brado (=grito) do o povo foi tão retumbante (=forte e alto) que até as margens do Ipiranga ouviram-no (figura de linguagem).

#### Mais informações

https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6015.md

Comment: Então... Essa é outra forma de entendimento que já ouvi algunas vezes. O problema dessa análise é que o brado foi dado "ao vento", para as margens. Ora, quem é que vai bradar pra um lugar que não tem ninguém? Só as margens ouviram o brado? Ou o povo bradou pra si mesmo por alegria e as margens ouviram? É meio estranho uma margem ouvir. Até entendo que pode ser uma personalização da margem dando una nobreza ao local, mas que é estranho personalizar uma margem é.

Comment: Vc sabe de algum documento oficial que corrobore a hipótese do hipérbato?

Comment: Além disso nessa versão citada vc colocou "e brado" ao invés de "o brado". Onde vc encontrou essa versão?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira adicionei a figura de prosopopeia, que explica o fato das margens ouvirem. No site do [Senado](https://www12.senado.leg.br/noticias/especiais/arquivo-s/antes-da-versao-atual-letra-do-hino-nacional-bajulava-pedro-i) há a informação sobre o hino e o hipérbato (apesar disso, a grande maioria dos gramáticos entendem dessa forma). Coloquei *e brado*, pois foi dessa forma que ele foi oficializado em 1922. O hino (Versão 1922) está disponível na [Câmara](https://www2.camara.leg.br/legin/fed/decret/1920-1929/decreto-15671-6-setembro-1922-487497-republicacao-91987-pe.html)

Comment: Excelente. Com essas fontes oficiais, considero explicado. Gratidão.

Comment: Idéia: seria bom colocar esses 2 links no corpo sua resposta

Comment: Exatamente: e se você estivesse naquelas margens, também teria ouvido. No fundo, o fato que as margens ouviram inclui qualquer pessoa que estivesse lá naquele momento. Ou seja: o brado retumbante de um povo heroico se ouvia na margens do Ypiranga. Para manter o efeito poético e mêtrico, foi preciso dar às margens um papel humano (a prosopopeia) e era impossível pronominalizar o verbo da frase, né? O verso não teria funcionado. Esse é o jeitinho da coisa.

Answer (score 3):

**Resposta curta, conforme aprendi no curso primário:**

- Quem ouviu  - foram as margens plácidas
- Quem falou (bradou)  - foi um povo heróico
- O que foi ouvido  - o brado retumbante
- O que falou (bradou) - algo que não é citado nesse parágrafo, e que nos ensinaram ter sido "Independência ou Morte"
- Onde estavam quem ouviu e quem falou - quem ouviu foram as próprias margens do riacho. Portanto, quem falou (bradou) estava em suas proximidades.

Uma vez que não há ocorrência de crase em "as margens plácidas", o parágrafo pode ser re-escrito da seguinte forma:

**"As margens plácidas do (riacho) Ipiranga ouviram o brado retumbante de um povo heroico, enquanto o sol da liberdade brilhava no céu da pátria em raios fúlgidos."**

Caso o autor tivesse colocado um acento grave em "as margens", mudaria o sentido para "Alguém que estava próximo, ou aqueles que estavam junto as margens do riacho Ipiranga, ouviram o brado retumbante..."

Mais detalhes em

[**Hino Nacional Brasileiro**](https://www.hinonacionalbrasileiro.net/significado-hino-nacional.php)

[**Você entende a letra do Hino Nacional Brasileiro**](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/curiosidades/hino.php)

[**Hino Nacional explicado tim-tim por tim-tim**](http://blogs.correiobraziliense.com.br/dad/hino-nacional-explicado-tim-tim-por-tim-tim/)

Comment: Quanto à parte onde vc diz o que foi falado, há controvérsias. No resto vc está certo porque o @Valdeir Psr apresentou as provas que assim é. Mas se quiser, leia os comentários que eu coloquei em outras respostas pra ver que não é tão simples e que essas afirmações precisam ser corroboradas por uma fonte oficial ou podem ser entendidas de várias outras formas.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira  Antigamente a letra do Hino Nacional era ensinada e explicada no curso primário de todas as escolas públicas do país.  (não sei se ainda é assim). Mais tarde, no ginásio, aprendíamos fazer sua análise sintática.  Minha resposta começa com "conforme aprendi no curso primário", ou melhor, conforme determinava o Ministério da Educação na época.  Referências, eu as acrescentei no final.

Comment: Sim, mas no caso essas páginas que colocou como referência, assim como seus professores não têm qualquer autoridade para dizer qual a interpretação correta, já o Planalto, Congresso e Senado têm sim autoridade pra isso. Além disso, no caso de sala de aula não pise haver a certeza da letra apresentada ser a correta. Por isso falei das referências nos comentários da outra responsta que eu aceitei. Porque citavam fontes oficiais que corroboram o que foi dito e não páginas que podem ter opiniões diversas.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira   Considero encerrada aqui essa discussão infrutífera.  Se quiser discutir em sala de Chat estarei à sua disposição.

Answer (score 2):

Não havendo acento, *as margens plácidas* poderiam ser ou sujeito ou objeto direto (respetivamente as margens ouviram ou foram ouvidas). Mas avançando para o verso seguinte, encontramos *o brado retumbante*, que está no singular, enquanto o verbo está no plural, pelo que *o brado retumbante* só pode ser objeto direto (semanticamente, também faz mais sentido termos um *brado* que é ouvido) e *as margens plácidas* só pode ser então sujeito. Por isso, a frase equivale a, numa ordem mais normal:

> As margens plácidas ouviram, (vindo) do Ipiranga, o brado retumbante de um povo heróico.

Comment: O Ipiranga é um córrego na cidade de São Paulo. Sendo assim, o povo que deu o brado estaria dentro do córrego ?

Comment: Estou fazendo essa pergunta pq algumas pessoas argumentam que no 1o verso haveria uma inversão e a ordem correta seria "ouviram as margens plácidas do Ipiranga". Por essa compreensão não caberia o "vindo do".

Answer (score 0):

Opa, infelizmente não vou poder te dar em detalhes semânticos do que está rolando ali.(minha gramática não é tão boa) Porém, creio eu, que deva se levar em consideração, não apenas a letra, mas também como se é cantado, afinal é um hino. Tendo isso em mente, o que foi ouvido, foram as margens plácidas(que remete ao sossego do rio) e o brado retumbante(que poderia remeter ou aos indígenas assassinados - em uma tentativa de dar valor aos oponentes sobre a vitoria do 'povo brasileiro'. Ou aos combatentes do lado vitorioso).
Sei que não foi tão conciso quanto gostaria, mas espero ter contribuído de alguma forma.

Answer (score -1):

Bem vou aqui dar minha contribuição para tal dilema, vamos supor que o autor desta letra queria dizer o seguinte: "Algumas (ou muitas) pessoas ouviram às margens plácidas do Ypiranga o brado retumbante de um povo heroico, e o sol da liberdade brilhou  no céu da pátria em raios fúlgidos, neste instante." Uma vez observando este meu ponto de vista, o sujeito aqui seria indeterminado, e "as margens plácidas" seria um adjunto adnominal relativo ao rio Ypiranga. Foi assim que aprendi com minha professora de português na década de 1980 onde se ensinava português, literatura e redação, e hoje o que é ensinado????

Comment: Wellerson, muito obrigado pela contribuição, mas há um grande erro na tua interpretação, que é ***às** margens plácidas*, sendo que a versão oficial e original é *as margens plácidas*. Por sinal, na última  que chequei, hoje se ensinam gramática, literatura e redação no Ensino Médio...

Comment: Olá Wellerson, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que o autor da pergunta deixou bastante claro (e em negrito) que "as margens" não leva crase, o que compromete tua interpretação. E seu comentário/pergunta final é desnecessário e uma distração indesejável.