# Quem tem boca vai a ou vaia Roma?

Tags: ditados, expressões-populares

É muito comum — ao menos no Brasil — ouvir a frase: *"Quem tem boca vai a Roma"*. Porém, vez ou outra, escuto que o correto é *"Quem tem boca vaia Roma"*.

#### Supostas explicações

*"Quem tem boca vai a Roma"*

> Ao se perder, uma pessoa pode perguntar a outras pessoas como chegar a um determinado lugar. Dessa forma, ela pode chegar a qualquer local.

*"Quem tem boa vaia Roma"*

> Os defensores desta expressão afirmam que ela surgiu após o povo revoltar-se contra alguns atos dos imperadores. Por causa isso, todos os vaiavam como sinal de protesto

Afinal de contas, qual a expressão original ou correta? E quando ela surgiu?

Comment: Acredito que seja a primeira, já que todos sabiam onde ficava Roma. A segunda provavelmente vem da etimologia criativa que sempre aparece na Internet.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Ambas frases estão corretas a depender do contexto.

### Explicações

#### **"Quem tem boca vaia Roma"**

É sabido por muitos que alguns imperadores tiveram algumas crises durante suas vidas, exemplo:

- Calígula, o *"pervertido"*;
- Cláudio, o *"paranoico"*; e
- Nero, o *"incendiário"*.

Por isso, de acordo com o escritor *Elio Marchand*, no livro *Quebrando O Código Da Bíblia*, o correto é "vaia Roma", pois essa era uma forma de convidar o povo ao protesto, que na ocasião era representado pelas "vaias".

Encontramos também essa expressão na música *Quem tem boca vaia Roma*, do *César MC*.

> Contra injustiça, minha alma berra
>   Até que a própria justiça retorne à terra.
>   Venci as batalha, pois nasci na guerra
>   E *quem tem boca vaia Roma*
>   Quem tem peito enfrenta o César!

Nesta canção, ele usa o ditado com o verbo *vaiar* para informar aos ouvintes que todos podem criticar e enfrentar um governo ou um sistema (de modo geral).

#### **"Quem tem boca vai a Roma"**

Ao que tudo indica, este é o ditado original, possivelmente do século XVII. No livro *"Portuguese and English: and English and Portuguese ... in Two Volumes, Volume 1"*, lançado em 1773, encontramos a seguinte explicação para esse ditado:

> (Original) that is, a man may go any where if he has language to speak for himself, and all the way
>   (Tradução) isto é, um homem pode ir a qualquer lugar se tiver linguagem para falar por si mesmo e por todo o caminho

Na peça de teatro *"Farça Intitulada Manoel Mendes"* (1812), também encontramos a expressão com o verbo "ir" no presente do indicativo

> “Se quem tem boca vai a Roma, V.m. pela grandeza da sua póde ir ao fim do Mundo...”

Além da língua portuguesa, podemos encontrar o ditado noutros idiomas:

- Em Italiano, *chi lingua ha, a Roma va*
- Em Francês, *qui langue a, à Rome va*
- Em Espanhol, *preguntando se va a Roma*
- Em Tcheco, *kdo jazyk má, do Ríma se doptá*

#### Variações

Também é possível deparamos-nos com algumas variações em português.

- Quem tem língua vai a Roma
- Quem língua tem a Roma vai e de Roma vem
- Quem tem língua a Roma vai e vem

***Fonte e Referências:***
https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6235.md

Comment: Valdeir, imagino que você tenha colocado o link to github com o texto + as referências para aumentar o tráfego nele, mas penso que seria mais adequado colocar as referências aqui também.

Comment: pequena correção: "ha", "lingua" e "va" não têm acento em italiano

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Corrigirei. Grato pela informação.

Comment: @stafusa Na verdade não é pelo tráfego. Os pontos são: 1) Organização, visto que participo de outras redes do *StackExchange*; 2) Às vezes, eu adiciono informações/curiosidades que talvez não fique legal na resposta, vide [Hino Nacional Stack](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6019/2759) e [Hino Nacional Git](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6015.md); 3) Por causa de direitos autorais de terceiros, visto que já excluíram uma questão inteira no *pt.stackoverflow.com* por causa de um termo que eu havia adicionado na minha resposta. (continua)

Comment: 4) Não sei se entendi bem (sou péssimo em inglês), mas não achei "tão legal" o item 6 dos [termos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/legal) do site, de modo que atualmente prefiro postar o conteúdo no git e aplicar apenas uma cópia dele aqui. Podemos abrir, inclusive, um questão no [Meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/) para deixar claro para os usuários.

Comment: Ah, interessante isso, abre a questão no meta sim (apesar de que talvez te dirijam para o meta geral, já que os termos não devem ser específicos).